# VMWare vRealize Operations REST API java password prompt for basic auth

Tags: java, vmware

With the code I'm using VMWare created an object factory to use with their Rest API. One of them is a clientconfig class which allows me to connect to the Rest API Service.

I'm trying to prompt the user to input the password versus storing it in my java client. I suspect I have to remove the basicauth object and replace it, however I'm hoping there might be an easier way.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Client client = ClientConfig
            .builder()
            .serverUrl("https://vrops-ip-address/suite-api")
            .basicAuth("admin", "password")
            .verify("false")
            .useJson()
            .build()
            .newClient();

        // retrieve list of all adapter instances
        AdapterInstancesInfoDto adapterInstances = client.adapterInstancesClient().list();

        // get actual set of adapters

        Set<AdapterInstanceInfoDto> adapters = adapterInstances.getAdapterInstancesInfoDto();

        // iterate the set
        for (AdapterInstanceInfoDto adapter : adapters) {
            // print to console
            System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(adapter, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the basicauth object is as follows:

```
public Builder basicAuth(String username, String password) {
}
```

The builder class is read only so I can't change basicauth. Any reference or advice would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask for the password before you create the connection.

```
System.err.print("Username: ");
String user = System.console().readLine();
System.err.print("Password: ");
String password = System.console().readPassword();
try {
        Client client = ClientConfig
            .builder()
            .serverUrl("https://vrops-ip-address/suite-api")
            .basicAuth(username, password)
            .verify("false")
            .useJson()
            .build()
            .newClient();
.
.
.
```